# Insert users id to the patient in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I can't insert the id of the currently logged-in user while making the patient data.
I want the user to be able to add his own patients, but the problem is that when I add a new patient, the column id_user is null

I tried lots of ways but couldn't add id_user to the patient.
What do I miss?

This is my User Entity:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idUser;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String username;
    ...

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_user"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_role"))
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Patient> patients = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(Patient patient) {
        if (patient != null) {
            if (patients == null) {
                patients = new ArrayList<>();
            }
        patients.add(patient);
        patient.setUser(this);
        }
    }
```

Patient Entity:

```
   @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_patient")
    private int idPatient;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;    
}
```

Controller

```
 @RequestMapping("/addPatient")
    public String addPatient(Model theModel, HttpServletRequest request) {

        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        UserDetails userD = (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
        User u = userService.findByUsername(userD.getUsername());

        request.getSession().setAttribute("id_user", u.getIdUser());
//        int userId = user.getIdUser();
        int userId = (int) request.getSession().getAttribute("id_user");

        User user = new User();
        user.setIdUser(userId);
        
        Patient patient = new Patient();
        patient.setUser(user);

        theModel.addAttribute("patient", patient);

        return "user/patients/add-patient-dashboard";
    }

 @PostMapping("savePatient")
    public String savePatient(@ModelAttribute("patient") Patient thePatient, Model model) {
        patientService.save(thePatient);
        return "redirect:/user/allPatients";
    }
```

I try editing the User service from:

```
@Override
    public void save(User user) {
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

to:

```
@Override
    public void save(User user) {
        List<Patient> patients = user.getPatients();
        patients.forEach(patient -> user.add(patient));
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

**if someone can help me resolve this I would appreciate it since I'm struggling for a very long time with this**

[image]

Comment: If you don't send the user id from the form it will not be set. What you need to do is either store the patient created in the session (so it is reused between form submits) or get the user (again) in the save part of the sequence instead of when initially rendering the form.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @M.Deinu, you saved me! I finally solve this! First I saved the patient and then I added the user to the patient and then again saved the patient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to M Denium I finally solve the issue. I have moved the whole code from `addUser` to `saveUser` method:

```
@RequestMapping("/addPatient")
   public String addPatient(Model theModel) {
            
       Patient patient = new Patient();    
       theModel.addAttribute("patient", patient);
            
       return "user/patients/add-patient-dashboard";
   }
        
       @PostMapping("savePatient")
public String savePatient(@ModelAttribute("patient") Patient thePatient, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    patientService.save(thePatient);

    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    UserDetails userD = (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
    User u = userService.findByUsername(userD.getUsername());
    request.getSession().setAttribute("id_user", u.getIdUser());
    
    int userId = (int) request.getSession().getAttribute("id_user");
    User user = userService.findById(userId);
    thePatient.setUser(user);
    patientService.save(thePatient);

    return "redirect:/user/allPatients";
}
```

Comment: Why place it in the session to directly retrieve it? That doesn't make any sense. You can omit hose lines and just use `u.getIdUser()` no need to store it in the session.

Comment: Yes, I also deleted that whole part with sessions and I changed `int userId = (int) u.getIdUser();` later @M.Deinum